# Last array value overwrites others

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble understanding accessing values from an array. I thought I had it but now hit a wall. I have the following array:

```
array(3) {
  ["en_value"]=>
  string(11) "Motor yacht"
  ["es_value"]=>
  string(12) "Yate a motor"
  ["de_value"]=>
  string(10) "Motoryacht"
}
```

...which I am trying to get each value from using this code:

```
foreach ($typeArray as $key => $titleValue) {

    if ($key = 'en_value') {
        $titleTypeEn = $titleValue;

    } else if ($key = 'es_value') {
        $titleTypeEs = $titleValue;

    } else if ($key = 'de_value') {
        $titleTypeDe = $titleValue;

    }
}

echo "english: ".$titleTypeEn."\n";
echo "spanish: ".$titleTypeEs."\n";
echo "german: ".$titleTypeDe."\n";
```

...which gives me this output:

```
english: Motoryacht
Undefined variable: titleTypeEs ...
spanish:
Undefined variable: titleTypeDe ...
german:
```

I thought that by setting a value for each key I could then access them outside of the loop but obviously I've got that wrong (or I'm doing it wrong).

Also I don't understand why the en_value gets set but then ends up with the last keys value? Help and guidance are appreciated.

Comment: You have assignments in your ifs. You need to use `if ($key == ...`, or even better if `($key === ...`.

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach` array to reassign the variables instead of referencing the array directly? `echo 'english: ' . $typeArray['en_value'];` is a far easier way to do this

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to assign them to separate variables. Replace your code with this:

```
echo "english: ".$typeArray['en_value']."\n";
echo "spanish: ".$typeArray['es_value']."\n";
echo "german: ".$typeArray['de_value']."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Obviously I was complicating this way more than I had to :).

Comment: No problem! Please accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks you for accepting.